# Beam - Is schema-agnostic ingestion/aggregation possible?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I want to ingest a stream of objects (e.g. JSON) that have changing schemas, not known a priori, and apply a custom aggregation, known a priori.

Is it possible in Beam ?

Specifically, can it:

1. Ingest a list of (nested) JSON objects with changing schemas (in a [PCollection](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pcollection-characteristics)):
   `msg1 = {"product":"apple","price":{"currency":"JPY","amount":50}}`
   `msg2 = {"product":"apple","price":{"amount":70},"unuseful_field_for_this":"foo"}`
2. Apply custom aggregation over (global and updating) time window (in a [CombineFn](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.28.0/_modules/apache_beam/transforms/core.html#CombineFn)):
   `res = {"product":"apple","sales":120,"currency":"JPY"} <= Using JPY as default`

The below code shows a first attempt to be schema-agnostic by using tuples (with the function `CombinePerKey` proposed [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/aggregation/combineperkey/)), but doesn't demonstrate a "richer" use case as the above one.

Note: the transformation is triggered by a dummy message sent separately to PubSub.

**Code**

```
# Libraries

import random
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

# Generator function

def create_random_record(line):
 
    n_fields = random.randint(1,5)
    msg = {"key{}".format(i): i for i in range(1,n_fields)}
   
    # One possible msg: {'key1': 1, 'key2': 2}
    # Another possible msg: {'key1': 1, 'key2': 2, 'key3': 3}

    return msg

class msg_to_tuple_list(beam.DoFn):

    def process(self, msg):
        return [(k,v) for k,v in msg.items()]
  
# Run function

def run(argv=None, save_main_session=True):

  pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(save_main_session=True, streaming=True)
  
  with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
      
    input_subscription=MY_INPUT_SUBSCRIPTION
    output_table=MY_OUTPUT_TABLE
    
    _ = (p
        | 'Trigger from Pub/Sub' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=input_subscription).with_output_types(bytes)
        | 'Random generator' >> beam.Map(create_random_record)
        | 'Convert dict to tuple list' >> beam.ParDo(msg_to_tuple_list())
        | 'Window' >> beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(5))
        | 'Aggregation' >> beam.CombinePerKey(sum) # The function I'd like to accept any json..      
        )

# Run
run()
```

**Output**

```
('key1', 9)
('key2', 14)
('key3', 15)
('key4', 8)
```

Comment: I believe the issue is with the `Map(print)`, note that the function `print` does not return anything. Try take the prints out or add your own function that prints but return the element.

Comment: @Iñigo: Thanks for the hint. The issue remains, but I'll leave those prints out in the question.

Comment: Oh, I have just spotted the issue, you are returning a dictionary in `beam.Map(create_random_record)` rather than a key value.`CombinePerKey` expects a tuple where the first index is the key and the second the value. I am not sure how you mean to aggregate, you may need to add some extra logic.

Comment: Thanks. I've modified code to return list of tuples, plus added global time window. Same error.

Comment: OK, last fix (I was in my phone and could not see the whole code). I see a couple of mistakes there. *(1)* You are using an unbounded source (PubSub), so in order to aggregate, you need to split it into bounded data, so you need a window. `GlobalWindow` is the general window, so you are not actually splitting the data, try adding a `FixedWindow` or `SessionWindow` (depending your use case). *(2)* In the first `Map` you are returning a list, note `Map` is a One-to-one operation, since you want to return more than one element, use `FlatMap` or `ParDo`. Once you try this I'll add an actual answer

Comment: Great, thanks ! I've modified the code accordingly and in this form it is working. Now that this prototype seems to work..does it prove that schema-free aggregation is indeed possible ? Would it work on a global window that reads entire topic and gets regularly updated ? Is there any way to update the schema of a PCollection ?

Comment: The prototype flattens a variable-length tuple of elements (`Tuple[dict[str, int]]`) into elements with the same schema `{key: str, value: int}`. It is supported by Beam. But what do you mean by dynamic schema? If you want to flatten [attributes](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#using_attributes) of a pubsub message, you'll have to parse it after decoding. If you can parse it, it means at that moment, you know the schema(s) of the message. As long as your following transforms handles all known schemas (the type will be a Union[schemas...]) correctly, it should be fine.

Comment: @大ドア東: Thanks. I've reformulated the question. Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: @Iñigo: Thanks again for your guidance. I've reformulated the question and that should not change anymore. Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Are you always going to aggregate over "product" and "amount"? Is "amount" always going to be in the same field "price: amount" (even if there are other fields)?

Comment: 1) Yes, let's assume that we only aggregate on those fields (but glad if you know how to incorporate a new rule on the fly, too ;). 2) No, let's assume that we might have to scan the object struct to find a key containing "amount" (i.e. that its coordinate might change in different messages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been working on this for some time, bare in mind that you need to add some adjustments and test it on your side. Things you need to have in mind:

- For simplicity, the logic to find the key `price` is not in my example, but I had it in mind for the design. You would need to add it.
- Since we are going to be [accumulating elements](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#window-accumulation-modes) and a `GlobalWindow`, I am a bit afraid you may run into memory issues after some time. In theory, the combiner lifting should make DF to only store the accumulators and not the all the elements. I had a pipeline with a similar approach for 2 days with no issues, but in Java (should be the same).
- Some extra logic would be needed to match your exact use case, this would work as an idea.

I'm using an advanced combiner to (1) force the combiner lifting and (2) so you can add your key parsing logic. I used a trigger of 5 minutes, so the total sum per key would be updated every 5 mins (you can change the trigger if needed).

I'm going to start my code assuming you have already parsed the elements from your stream as we discussed in the comments. The elements entering my code are in this format:

```
        {"product": "apple", "price": {"currency": "JPY", "amount": 50}},
        {"product": "orange", "price": {"amount": 50}},
        {"product": "apple", "price": {"amount": 10}},
        {"product": "orange", "price": {"currency": "EUR", "amount": 50}},
        {"product": "apple", "price": {"currency": "JPY", "amount": 30}}
```

Those get passed to the pipeline:

```
    class NestedDictSum(beam.CombineFn):
        def create_accumulator(self):
            # accumulator instance starts at 0
            return 0

        def add_input(self, sum_value, input):
            # Called for every new element, add it to the accumulator
            return sum_value + self._get_price(input)

        def merge_accumulators(self, accumulators):
            # Called for every accumulator across workers / bundles
            return sum(accumulators)

        def extract_output(self, total):
            # output value from merged accumulators
            return {"sales": total, "currency": "JPY"}

        def _get_price(self, dictionary):
            # Add your logic to find the right key in it
            # Needs to return the parsed price (what you want to sum)
            return dictionary["price"]["amount"]

    def add_product(element):
        dictionary = element[1]
        dictionary["product"] = element[0]
        return dictionary

# Pipeline read stream and so on

     | Map(lambda x: (x["product"], x))  # To KV
     | WindowInto(GlobalWindows(),
                  trigger=trigger.Repeatedly(trigger.AfterProcessingTime(5 * 60)),
                  # This makes the elements not be discarded, so the value would
                  # be updated as new elements are triggered
                  accumulation_mode=trigger.AccumulationMode.ACCUMULATING)
     | CombinePerKey(NestedDictSum())
     | Map(add_product)  # From KV to Dictionary adding Key
```

The output of this is:

```
{'sales': 90, 'currency': 'JPY', 'product': 'apple'}
{'sales': 100, 'currency': 'JPY', 'product': 'orange'}
```

Note that in an actual Streaming case, this value would get updated every 5 mins

Also, I thinks this peculiar use case may benefit from using [**Stateful and Timely DoFN**](https://beam.apache.org/blog/timely-processing/). This will allow you control your elements with a finer grain and may be a better fit than what I posted.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort and the result ! I could re-run your code on my side. One note: each currency should be aggregated separately though. Only the values without currency should be defaulted to "JPY". Any way to improve your code and treat "EUR" as such ?

Comment: Sure, it would be as simple as creating another key before aggregating, you can do a "product+currency" or just aggregate twice. Another way could be to convert to the default currency in "_get_price"

Comment: Thanks ! Two bonus questions where your guidance with Beam would be appreciated (design pattern, libraries):  1) How would you incorporate an aggregation rule that requires access to some previous raw messages (e.g. pick default currency as the *mode*, i.e. the most frequent observed currency in the raw incoming messages) 2) Persist (say every 10x triggers) the raw/accumulator data on disk, read from it, and avoid memory issues ? Let me know if those would deserve new threads or trivial enough. Thanks !

Comment: (1) not sure I follow, but the concept of "previous" is fuzzy in Beam. I guess Stateful DoFns would be a good approach (2) data should be persisted automatically during the combiner (the merging), and if I'm not mistaken with the combiner lifting, only the accumulator would be persisted. Anyhow, here Stateful DoFns could help you handling the data even more flexible

Comment: Thanks a lot @Iñigo for your contribution in this tread.